# How to write a regex that validates alpha-numerics and spaces

Tags: regex, bash, function, shell

I am writing a bash validation function that sanitizes user input.

The idea is that if a script has 3 parameters, those could be only alpha-numeric values. BUT a parameter could be multiple words enclosed in double quotes like so:

`myfunction arg1 arg2 "this is arg3"`

So I am basically looking to strip everything out that is not an alpha-numeric or space character.

At the moment, i've got:

`validateEntry() { 
    string=$1 
    clean=${string//[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/}
}`

But it does not seem to work. In `myfunction arg1 arg2 "this is arg3"`, the `is arg3` is getting stripped out.

And the way I am using this function is in a script, like so:

```
name=$(validateEntry $1)
```

I need help with that.

## edit:

The idea is to use the `validateEntry` function in a script that can take, let's say, 3 arguments, like so:

```
if [[ "$#" -eq 3 ]]; then
    arg1=$(validateEntry $1)
    arg2=$(validateEntry $2)
    arg3=$(validateEntry $3)
    echo "${arg1}, ${arg2}, ${arg3}."
fi
```

But if my script's third argument is `this is arg3`, `$arg3` is reduced to `this`, even though when i call my the function directly, with the same three arguments, the third arg is `this is arg3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\s` does not mean "any type of whitespace" in a pattern (which is not a regular expression). Instead, either use just a literal space

```
clean=${1//[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]}
```

or, if you want to match spaces, tabs, newlines, etc, use the POSIX character class `[:space:]`:

```
clean=${1//[^a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]}
```

(For that matter, you can use character classes for the letters and numbers as well:

```
clean=${1//[^[:alnum:][:space:]]}
```

)

Once you've done that, there are two other things you need to change:

1. You need to actually output the cleaned-up value:

   ```
   validateEntry () {
      echo "${1//[^[a[:alnum:][:space:]]}"
   }
   ```
2. You need to quote the expansion you want to validate, so that the entire thing is passed to your function:

   ```
   name=$(validateEntry "$1")
   ```

Comment: I may have to note that I am running bash on OSX. Your three solutions don't seem to work.

Comment: If there are special characters in one of the double-quoted parameters (i.e., !@#%$), won't the shell expand the argument and throw an error?

Comment: This is how i use it: `validateEntry "This is my entry"
-bash: [[: This is my entry: syntax error in expression (error token is "is my entry")`

Comment: @shellter My condolences! :)

Answer (score 2):

**Edited to match the question.**

```
function validateEntry {
    echo ${1//[^[:alnum:][:space:]]/}
}


if [[ $# -eq 3 ]]; then
    echo $(validateEntry "$1")
    echo $(validateEntry "$2")
    echo $(validateEntry "$3")
fi
```

Command

```
./test.sh arg1 arg2 "this is arg3"
```

Output:

```
arg1
arg2
this is arg3
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. The output appears fine to me. You need to use the quotes properly.

Comment: Indeed, it was all about the quotes. Thank you!